# Viewcontroller not loading

Tags: ios, ipad

Working on a tabbed ipad application. My program builds but fails to launch with the error given below on this line from the AppDelegate.m,

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

This code has not been edited ie straight from the template and has worked correctly until now. The view controllers seem to initiate, and show valid properties in the inspector when debugging. I am assuming the NSrange error is referring to the self.tabBarController.viewControllers array, maybe that's not true.

Sorry , the error was in my own code, please ignore.

Comment: What did you change just before it stopped working? Something in `FirstViewController`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I finally tracked the error. Not surprising it was me all along, just couldn't find it. Error in the viewdidload.

Comment: Please delete the question rather than adding a note at the bottom to ignore. Or update the question and add an answer which shows what happens when you break `viewDidLoad` while adding controllers to a tab controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UIViewController *viewController_favorites = [[[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController_project = [[[ProjectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController_favorites,viewController_project, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```